# Range of the gradient

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, legendre-transformation

Let $f \in C^2(\Omega \subseteq \Bbb{R}^n)$ be a real valued and strictly convex (meaning that $(\partial_{ij}f(\underline{x}))$ is positive definite) function on a convex, open, connected subset $\Omega$ of $\Bbb R^n$. I would like to know wether there is some constraint that can be derived on the range of the gradient of $f$. The motivation behind this question is that I would like to characterize the domain of definition of the Legendre Transform of $f$.

Comment: If $f(x)=x^2$, then the grad is $2x$ and unconstrained on $\mathbb R$, right ?

Comment: @P.Quinton That is correct but by constraint I meant also topological properties such as “convexity” “openness” etc etc